# How do I combine the results of two queries in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My bad if I don't understand simple things, as I am just beginning to write SQL queries.

I have two queries:

> SELECT * FROM status WHERE   author IN (SELECT user1 FROM friends
>   WHERE user2='$username' AND accepted='1')   OR   author IN (SELECT
>   user2 FROM friends WHERE user1='$username' AND accepted='1')

and

> SELECT * FROM status WHERE   author = '$username'

How can I combine the results of these two queries, either natively in the SQL query, or in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `UNION`:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

To allow duplicate values, use the `ALL` keyword with UNION.

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

Comment: `UNOION` is not a right answer for this question. it is `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I just accepted an answer on another question by accident, but when the timer expires, I'll mark as correct :)

Comment: @Dubstaphone May be you need exactly `UNION`, but the term `combine` fits to `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just using `OR`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM status 
WHERE author IN (SELECT user1 FROM friends WHERE user2='$username' AND accepted='1') 
    OR author IN (SELECT user2 FROM friends WHERE user1='$username' AND accepted='1')
    OR author = '$username'
```